# Postgres problem

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have the following data in my table;

```
tran_date    withdraw     deposit
25/11/2010          0         500
2/12/2010         100           0
15/12/2010          0         300
18/12/2010          0         200
25/12/2010        200           0
```

Suppose I want to get the following for date range between 1/12/2010 and 31/12/2010.

```
tran_date    withdraw    deposit    balance     days_since_last_tran
1/12/2010           0          0        500                        0
2/12/2010         100          0        400                        1
15/12/2010          0        300        700                       13
18/12/2010          0        200        900                        3
25/12/2010        200          0        700                        7
31/12/2010          0          0        700                        6
```

Is this doable in PostgreSQL 8.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT t.tran_date,
       t.withdraw,
       t.deposit,
       (SELECT SUM(y.deposit) - SUM(y.withdrawl)
          FROM YOUR_TABLE y
         WHERE y.tran_date <= t.tran_date) AS balance,
       t.tran_date - COALESCE(LAG(t.tran_date) OVER(ORDER BY t.tran_date), 
                              t.tran_date) AS days_since_last
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

8.4+ is nice, providing [access to analytic/windowing functions like LAG](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html).

Comment: Giving me an error :: 'ERROR:  COALESCE types date and integer cannot be matched'

Comment: @OMG Ponies :: I still don't get the edges if I put on a date range.

Comment: @Rabin: "edges"?  I'm not telepathic -- if you want to apply a date range, state such in your question.

Comment: @OMG Ponies :: But I have said in my question that I want to apply date range and want to see the first and the last day of the date range though there may not be any transaction on those days.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: The 1st and last line in the proposed result do not correspond to a table entry.